# Como fazer para minha resposta que usa API do Google-Maps voltar a mostrar o resultado correto?

Tags: suporte, respostas

Faz um tempo que escrevi [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214587/64969) sobre achar o centro de um polígono no Google Mapas. Porém, ao verificar essa questão, me deparei com as seguintes mensagens:

> ```
> {
>   "message": "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property \"addEventListener\" on cross-origin object",
>   "filename": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js",
>   "lineno": 177,
>   "colno": 0
> }
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API error: MissingKeyMapError
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
> ```

E a imagem exibida passou a ser uma imagem de erro:

[image: ops, deu ruim o mapa]

Como devo prosseguir para exibir o mapa corretamente, de novo? Devo exibir minha chave na resposta?

Comment: Algumas coisas da API do Maps mudaram de uns tempos para cá. Dá um lida nas novidades. Uma delas é que em muitos casos somos obrigado a informar dados de pagamento, ou algo do tipo

Comment: Eu acho que não deve, né? :) Mas de fato não tem como demonstrar direito sem a chave, não parece ter uma solução adequada a não ser deixar mais ou menos, e sem poder executar.

Comment: @Maniero tava vendo como as pessoas estavam fazendo no SO internacional. Em pelo menos uma pergunta o AP colocou a própria chave. Eu vi em algum lugar que eu posso limitar a chave a uma site de origem específico, talvez seja o caminho menos bugoso...

Comment: E pode gerar uma chave só pra isso?

Comment: Não sei ‍♂️ Mas se não puder, vou começar a usar essas chaves vazadas no SO internacional para fins pessoais #sqn

Comment: Acredito que `.jpg` ou `.gif` seriam uma opção de demonstração. Pois mesmo a chave vazada pode ser um dia excluída, voltando a invalidar seu exemplo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, gostei da proposta. Só não consigo torná-la plenamente executável para provar o meu código. Sobre limitar a execução para sites de origem específico, eu li aqui https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369198/is-it-practical-to-have-a-google-maps-api-key-available-for-snippets#comment598323_369198

Comment: [Restringir a chave da API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#restrict_key) veja se ajuda.

Comment: Sinceramente eu acho que essa pergunta fica melhor no site principal.

Comment: @Bacco Eu vim aqui pra falar sobre isso. Parece uma pergunta pro site principal mesmo. Só teria que editar pra "encaixar" melhor lá.

Comment: A priori minha intenção era só corrigir minha resposta, por isso nem cogitei em por no site principal. Aceito sugestões de como formatar para melhor encaixar, LINQ e Bacco

Comment: Removi a resposta (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7970/3635) porque o Bacco me atentou ao comportamento no Firefox (quando formulei a resposta ainda usava o Opera, mesmo motor do Chrome): https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlVFM.png, o mapa só continua funcionando (parcialmente) no Chrome e navegadores baseados nele ... aposto que a Google fez isso só para dizer: *"tudo 'funciona' melhor no Chrome"* 

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nossa, Google googlando! "Don't do evil" pelo visto não se encaixa no browser wars moderno...

Comment: Tava pensando em como fazer com um diálogo para o usuário inserir dinamicamente a chave, mas sem tempo pra essa POC

Comment: "Don't BE Evil" ?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado parece uma saída, apesar da "burocracia", eu vou ser sincero, me parece que o caminho para ilustrar vai ser mesmo um printscreen :/ ... mas se a intenção for mesmo um dialogo pedindo a apikey, valeria uma pergunta no site principal, eu arriscaria uma resposta :)